# What I am missing to make this into a simple substitution cipher to encrypt and decrypt a message?

Tags: java, encryption

So I had this assignment I ended up turning in late, but in my heart I don't feel like I wrote the program correctly.  It's eating at me and I really want to understand what I did wrong.  so here is the assignemnt:

> Write a program that can perform encryption and decryption using an
>   arbitrary substitution cipher. In this case, the encryption array is a
>   random shuffling of all the printable ASCII characters (including
>   character: space).

Also included was an idea for a shuffle:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

    public class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Character[] original = new Character[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};
        Character[] encrypted = new Character[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};

        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(encrypted));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(encrypted));
      }
    }
```

and this is what I came up with:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Caesar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter anything: ");
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();

        char[] original = input.toCharArray();
        char[] encrypted = input.toCharArray();
        String a = new String(original);

        // Ask if we would like to encrypt
        System.out.print("Shall we encrypt? (Y/N): ");
        char selection = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        selection = Character.toUpperCase(selection);

        if (selection == 'Y') {
            // Encryption process
            shuffleArray(encrypted);
            System.out.print("Encrypted message: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(encrypted[i]);
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Shall we decrypt? Y/N: ");
            selection = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            selection = Character.toUpperCase(selection);
            if (selection == 'Y') {
                System.out.println("Decrypted message: " + a);
            } 
        } else if (selection == 'N') {
            System.out.print("Nothing was done to the text: " + a);
        } else {
            System.out.println("You must enter either Y or N!");
        }
    }

    static void shuffleArray(char[] ar) {
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Simple swap
            char a = ar[index];
            ar[index] = ar[i];
            ar[i] = a;
        }
    }
}
```

it started as a Caesar cipher but I got fed up and ended up simple using a random shuffle, the problem is the encryption is only good for that instance. I want to be able to decrypt a message reliably even with other instances occurring in between. I can almost see the solution in my head, but it's just out of reach.  Can anyone help me connect the dots?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions don't really make sense. The principle of encryption is

- you have some clear text to encrypt
- you have a secret key
- you apply an algorithm using that key to encrypt the clear text

Encrypted text must be possible to transform back to clear text **if you know the secret key**. So, in the instructions, what the teacher refers to as "the encryption array" is, probably, the secret key.

Your algorithm just randomly shuffles the clear text, without using any key. So it's not possible to decrypt anymore. For example, if you receive "lloa" as the encrypted text, the clear text might be "allo" or "lola", and there's no way to know.

Here's what *I think* the teacher meant.

The **key** is an array of 27 elements containing all the letters + space in a random order. For example :

```
K I Z R ...
```

Since K is at the first position in the key, that means that all the A occurring in the clear text must be transformed into K. Since I is at the second position in the key, that means that all the B in the clear text must be transformed into I, etc. etc.

The decryption algorithm is simple if you know the key: K must be transformed into A, I must be transformed into B, etc.

Collections.shuffle() is just an easy way to generate a random key from the array of letters. Once you have a random key, you can use it to encrypt the clear-text, and to then decrypt the encrypted text. The test is simple: the decrypted text must be equal to the original clear text (provided you used the same key, of course).